# Set font for numbers in Polyglossia

Tags: fonts, fontspec, languages, polyglossia, ucharclasses

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{CMU Serif} % English font
\newfontfamily\thaifont[Script=Thai]{TH Sarabun New} % Thai font
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{thai}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th_TH"

\begin{document}
\section{ทดสอบ \englishfont{test}}
ว่างเปล่า empty0 \englishfont{empty1}
\end{document}
```

This code builds

[image]

Is there any way to use CMU Serif font for the section number without changing `\setdefaultlanguage` because most of the document is still written in Thai but I only want to change the font for numbers.

I also know that `ucharclass` package can do this but it is a bit outdated and doesn't have maintainer anymore.

Comment: `\renewcommand\thesection{\englishfont\arabic{section}}`?